# Format Strings -- Pad a double left and right

Tags: c#, string, format-string

*I am almost to embarrassed to ask this very basic question, but:*

How do you print the following **only using format strings**?

```
42.315 -->  42.315000
-4.2   -->  -4.200000
315.42 --> 315.420000
```

*if it was not noticable: I require a padding with spaces **before** the comma/dot **and** a zero-padding **after** the comma/dot*

---

I have the following code to pad the following zeros:

```
double v1 = 42.315;

return string.Format("v1: {0:F14}", v1);
```

And I would normally use `<string>.PadLeft(18, ' ')` to pad the left side of the string with zeros.
I do, however, want to avoid `string::PadLeft(int, char)` and solve this issue purely with `string::format(string, params object[])`.

---

*I am pretty sure, that this has been asked about a hundred times here - though I was unable to find the question(s). But feel free to mark it as a duplicate [only if it is one - of course] ...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the padding between the index and the colon:

```
string.Format("v1: {0,18:F14}", v1)
```

Result:

```
v1:  42.31500000000000
```

This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#control-spacing).

Comment: Perfect - I even tried using `"v1: {0:F14:18}"` as I thought, that it was something along these lines, but it did not work. Thank you, for your answer, Sir :)